# ResourceLocation throws a FileNotFoundException Minecraft Forge 1.12.2

Tags: java, resources, textures, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm doing some Minecraft Mods and I don't know why the texture of an entity is not getting loaded

For the Texture:
`public static final ResourceLocation TEXTURES = new ResourceLocation(Reference.MODID+":textures/entity/test/test.png");`

here is the Modid
`public static final String MODID = "aot";`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: aot:textures/entity/test/test.png
```

[packagetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQSAC.png)

Why are the textures not getting loaded?

Best regards

Comment: In your packagetree, it looks like there are dots instead of slashes, or are these ide related? Also, you are using `MODID + ":textures..."`, why are you using an ":"?

Comment: @Luca100 The dots are IDE related, OP is probably using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public static final ResourceLocation TEXTURES = new ResourceLocation(Reference.MODID+":textures/entity/test/test.png");
```

use

```
public static final ResourceLocation TEXTURES = new ResourceLocation(Reference.MODID, "textures/entity/test/test.png");
```

But that won't work if you have named the packages with dots and not with seperate folders!